# TypeError: f_p() argument after * must be an iterable, not numpy.float64

Tags: python, arrays, vector, complex-numbers

I'm coding an algorithm that takes the inverse of a Laplace transform, iterates it until it converges and live-plots the graph. I've dealt with a bunch of errors so far and solved them all but on this one, I'm stumped. Here's the function `f_p()` that I'm getting the error from. For context, it contains 6 Laplace transforms that I painstakingly derived by hand to eliminate the imaginary component:

```
def f_p(u, omega, m):
    a = gamma
    b = (omega + k * math.pi) / u

    if m == 1:
        f = a * (1 / (a ** 2 + (b + 1) ** 2) + 1 / (a ** 2 + (b - 1) ** 2))
        return f * math.cos(omega)
    elif m == 2:
        f = a / (a ** 2 + b ** 2)
        return f * math.cos(omega)
    elif m == 3:
        f = math.e ** (-a / (a ** 2 + b ** 2)) * (a ** 2 + b ** 2) ** (1 / 4) * math.cos(
            (math.atan2(b, a) + 2 * n * math.pi) / 2) * math.cos(b / (a ** 2 + b ** 2)) / (
                    math.sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2) * (math.cos((math.atan2(b, a) + 2 * n * math.pi) / 2) ** 2 + math.sin(
                        (math.atan2(b, a) + 2 * n * math.pi) / 2)))
        return f * math.cos(omega)
    elif m == 4:
        a = math.e
        f = -(a * math.log(a ** 2 + b ** 2) + a ** 2) / (a ** 2 + b ** 2)
        return f * math.cos(omega)
    elif m == 5:
        f = a * (math.e ** (-a) * math.cos(b) - math.e ** (-2 * a) * math.cos(2 * b)) / (a ** 2 + b ** 2)
        return f * math.cos(omega)
    elif m == 6:
        f = math.sqrt((a ** 2 - b ** 2 + 1) ** 2 + (2 * a * b) ** 2) * math.cos(
            (math.atan2(2 * a * b, a ** 2 - b ** 2 + 1) + 2 * n * math.pi) / 2) / (
                    ((a ** 2 - b ** 2 + 1) ** 2 + (2 * a * b) ** 2) * (
                        math.cos((math.atan2(2 * a * b, a ** 2 - b ** 2 + 1) + 2 * n * math.pi) / 2) ** 2 + math.sin(
                            (math.atan2(2 * a * b, a ** 2 - b ** 2 + 1) + 2 * n * math.pi) / 2) ** 2))
        return f * math.cos(omega)
    else:
        return 0
```

This function feeds into another function `f_u()`, which contains the algorithm itself, which integrates over `omega`, removing it as a variable. The remaining variable is `u`, which I need  to iterate until the function converges. Here's the execution of the algorithm:

```
u = np.linspace(0.000001, 100, 100000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)

    for m in range(1, 7):
        if m == 4:
            gamma = math.e
        else:
            gamma = 10

        pool.map(f_u, u)
```

Maybe it could be a syntax problem? I don't know. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your map is not correct. I think it is iterating through the u array, calling f_u for each value.

Comment: @Stargazer I don't think so. I just swapped u and f_u and it gave me another error saying it wasn't "iterable"

Comment: It is not swapping, the mapping is just not working how you think it works.

Comment: I can't find the mistake in your code, but this error message is created if the `*` unary unpacking operator (to pass several arguments to a function) is applied to something that is not an iterator. This can happen e.g. if one tries to create a 1-tuple with `(1)`, while the correct syntax is `(1,)`.